# I lost bronze badges!

Tags: discussion

I have seen that my badges ***count(badges) =  count(badges)-1***.

The badges also can taken away like the reputation.

I just lost one bronze badges.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Previously i have 36 bronze badges. Now its 35.

Comment: Whatever it was, you're back up to 36 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only badges that are removed are the tag badges, like [8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/123/8). The other badges are never removed; if the conditions to have a badge (which is not a tag badge) are not verified anymore, the badge is not removed, but you will not gain another badge of the same type.